# How to change screens in homepage widget upon pressing of bottom nav bar button

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have provided MapPage() and BottomNavBar() widget to the body property in **HomePage** widget and I want that whenever I press my center floating button of BottomNavBar() the MapPage() widget changes to NearbyMechanics().

**This is my HomeScreen() class**

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
     
      body: const MapPage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
    ));
  }
}
```

**This is my BottomNavBar class**

```
class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  var currentIndex = 0;
  bool? centerModelOpen;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
      
      bottomBarCenterModel: BottomBarCenterModel(
        centerBackgroundColor: kButton,
        centerIcon: const FloatingCenterButton(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.car_crash_rounded,
            color: AppColors.white,
            size: 32,
          ),
        ),
        centerIconChild: [
         * FloatingCenterButtonChild(
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.build,
                  color: AppColors.white,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Nearby Mechanics",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 6.5),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {
//Apply logic of showNearbyMechanics
            },
          ),*
          FloatingCenterButtonChild(
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.local_hotel_rounded,
                  color: AppColors.white,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Nearby Hotels",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 6.5),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          FloatingCenterButtonChild(
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.local_gas_station_rounded,
                  color: AppColors.white,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Nearby Pumps",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 6.5),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to change MapPage() widget to NearbyMechanics() widget whenever I press the nearby mechanics button. How can I do that?

I tried making a bool type variable showMechanics and set is to true after pressing the bottom button and tried to show NearbyMechanics screen if it was true but the problem was that it was declared in a seperate class

Answer (score 1):

In your scaffold the body should be a list of widgets [] that you want to change (the screens) bottom nav buttons should be the same number of the pages

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final int currentIndex = 0;
final List<Widget> screensList = [your screens here];
return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    body: screensList[currentIndex],
  bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
  ));
 }
}
```

and then on the onTap function just change the currentIndex variable to the screen index that you want to go to ex:

```
 FloatingCenterButtonChild(
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            Icon(
              Icons.local_gas_station_rounded,
              color: AppColors.white,
            ),
            Text(
              "Nearby Pumps",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 6.5),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () {setState({currentIndex = 1;})},
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My bottom nav bar is a separate class and set state will build only the bottom nav bar again instead of homepage screen. How can I refresh the homepage screen so that it shows the particular widget depending upon index.

Comment: @HassamJaved Even if it's on a different class it must rebuild the whole screen not just the navBar